# If $|y|=e^c e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ and $e^c \neq 0$, why in $y=ae^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$, $a$ can be 0?

Tags: integration

I am reading the following note:
[image]

I do not quite understand the last statement. If $|y|=e^c e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ and $e^c \neq 0$, why in $y=ae^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$, $a$ can be 0?

Comment: Because $y(x) = 0$ is a solution of your ODE $y^\prime (x) = - x y(x)$ which luckily enough can be obtained from the representation formula $y(x) = a e^{-x^2/2}$ for non-zero solutions.

Comment: Probably your first step was to divide both sides by $y$, and it can be done if $y \neq 0$. But $y = 0$ is a solution.

Comment: Like the others say, it is a happy coincidence that we can combine all three possible solutions (positive, negative, and zero) into one notation.